# countdown formatting showing more than 23hs in the hour variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue making this countdown, it shows more hours than "23". Any idea how to fix it?

```
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function() {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10);
    var days = Math.floor(sec_num / 86400);
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
    

    return days + " days" + " : " + hours + " hrs" + " : " + minutes + " min" + " : " + seconds + " sec";
  };
  
  
  let startTime = 1649303300; // database unix-timestamp value
  setInterval(() => {
    let curTime = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
    curTime = parseInt(curTime);
  

    if (curTime < startTime){
        document.getElementById("timer1").innerText = ("LAUNCHING IN:");
        document.getElementById("timer").innerText = (`${startTime-curTime}`).toHHMMSS();
        
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("timer1").innerText = ("LAUNCHED");
        document.getElementById("timer").innerText = ("");
    }
    
    
  }, 1000);
```

"

I'm getting more than "23" for the "hours" variable instead of increasing the days every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not subtracting the days from the `hours` variable in the way that you're doing it for `minutes` and `seconds`. Try declaring your hours variable like this:

```js
var days = Math.floor(sec_num / 86400);
var hours = Math.floor((sec_num - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
```

You can also use modular arithmetic to strip the excess values. You can use the modulo operator for this, e.g.

```js
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function() {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10);
    var days = Math.floor(sec_num / 86400);
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600) % 24;
    var minutes = Math.floor(sec_num / 60) % 60;
    var seconds = sec_num % 60;
    

    return days + " days" + " : " + hours + " hrs" + " : " + minutes + " min" + " : " + seconds + " sec";
  };
```